# int to double or double to int

Tags: java

So I basically want to know, does java automatically turn int to a double or a double to a int.

To make this more clear look at this example:
say where given this heading

```
 public static void doThis (int n, double x)
```

and in the main method we declare something like this :

```
doThis(0.5,2);
```

Is this a invalid call?

how about this?

```
doThis(3L,4);
```

these last two

```
doThis(3,4);
doThis(2.0,1.5);
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just compile them and see?

Answer (score 2):

Values of type `int` can be implicitly converted to `double`, but not vice versa.

Given this declaration:

```
public static void doThis (int n, double x)
```

these are legal:

```
doThis(1, 0.5); // call doThis with an int and a double
doThis(1, (double)2); // second int is converted to a double, then passed
doThis(1, 2); // same as above; the compiler automatically inserts the cast
doThis((int)3.5, 0.5); // first double is converted to an int, then passed
doThis((int)3.5, 42); // the double is converted to an int, and the int is converted to a double
```

and these are not:

```
doThis(5.1, 0.5); // the compiler will not automatically convert double to int
doThis(5L, 0.5); // nor will it convert long to int
```

The intention behind the automatic conversion rules is that the compiler will not automatically convert types if doing so could lose data. For example, `(int)4.5` is 4, not 4.5 - the fractional part is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an `int` literal where a double is required, but not vice versa. If you try to compile the following example, you can see for yourself.

```
public class MWE{ 
    public static void doThis (int n, double x) {

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doThis(0.5,2); // Compiler error
        doThis(3L,4);// Compiler error
        doThis(3,4); // No Error
        doThis(2.0,1.5); // Compiler error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, you can pass `int` when `double` is needed(it get casted by the compiler).

But you cant pass `double` in place of `int`.

More info over [here](http://mrbool.com/java-data-type-conversion/29257).

Comment: Technically you're not passing an `int` - the compiler inserts a cast to `double`, and then the `double` is passed.

Comment: @immibis: Yes agreed. Thats what they call it as *datatype narrowing*, if I'm correct.

Answer (score 1):

When passing values of different types, there are a couple of rules of thumb:

1. Floating points cannot be substituted for integers, but the reverse is possible.
2. Primitives of the same type (integer or floating point) with a higher but depth cannot be substituted for ones with lower bit depth, but the reverse is possible.

Substitution is just an automatic cast by the Java compiler. You can always cast manually.

To clarify, the floating point types are `float` and `double`, while the integer types are `byte`, `short`, `int`, and `long`.

In this case, `double` is a floating point and `int` is an integer. You can substitute `int` in place of a `double`, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

In a method invocation, each argument value can have any of these conversions applied to it ([JLS 5.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3)):

> ### 5.3. Method Invocation Conversion
>
> Method invocation contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - **a widening primitive conversion** (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by widening reference
>     conversion
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening
>     primitive conversion.

In this example, we're dealing with a [primitive widening conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2):

> #### 5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion
>
> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening
>   primitive conversions:
>
> - `byte` to `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - `short` to `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - `char` to `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - `int` to `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - `long` to `float` or `double`
> - `float` to `double`

As you can see in the list, going from a `int` to `double` is perfectly fine, but the opposite is not true.